# Proof Check: Prove Relation Between Invariants Is the Only Relation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, invariant-theory

Consider the finite matrix group $C_{4} \subset$ GL$(2,\mathbb{C})$ generated by

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} i & 0 \\ 0 & -i \end{bmatrix} \in \text{GL}(2,\mathbb{C}).$$

(a)Prove that $C_{4}$ is cyclic of order 4.

(b)Use the method of Example 13 to determine $\mathbb{C}[x,y]^{C_{4}}$.

(c)Is there an algebraic relation between the invariants you found in part (b)? Can you give an example to show how uniqueness fails?

(d)Use the method of Exercise 13 to show that the relation found in part (c) is the only relation between the invariants.

I am comfortable with my results for parts (a) through (c) and in particular I found that the ring of invariants, $\mathbb{C}[x,y]^{C_{4}}$ = $[x^4, y^4, xy].$

I identified the relation $x^4 \cdot y^4 = (xy)^4$ so that uniqueness fails.

As mentioned above I was instructed to

> (d) Use the method of exercise 13 to show that the relation found is the only relation between invariants.

Where exercise 13 states

> We discovered the algebraic relation $x^2 \cdot y^2 = (xy)^2$ between the invariants $x^2, y^2, xy$. We want to show that this is essentially the only relation. More precisely, suppose that we have a polynomial $g(u,v,w) \in k[u,v,w]$ such that $g(x^2,y^2,xy) = 0$. We want to prove that $g(u,v,w)$ is a multiple (in $k[u,v,w]$) of $uv-w^2$ (which is the polynomial corresponding to the relation).
>
> (a) If we divide $uv-w^2$ using lex order with u>v>w, show that the remainder can be written in the form $uA(u,w) + vB(v,w) + C(w)$.
>
> (b) Show that a polynomial $r =uA(u,w) + vB(v,w) + C(w)$ satisfies $r(x^2, y^2, xy) = 0$ if and only if $r = 0$.

But I didn't quite understand that method, so what I said instead (switching back to my ring of invariants) was

> Let $g(u,v,w) \in \mathbb{C}[u,v,w]$ such that $g(x^4,y^4,xy)=0$. Let $f_{1} = uv-w^4 \in \mathbb{C}[u,v,w]$ be the polynomial that corresponds to my identified relation. Dividing $g$ by $f_{1}$ with respect to lex order and $u>v>w$ we have
>   $$g = a_{1}(uv-w^4) + r,$$
>   where $r$ = 0 or $r$ is a linear combination of monomials with coef in $\mathbb{C}$, where no monomial divisible by LT$(f_{1}) = uv$. If $r$ = 0 we are done, since that implies $g$ is a multiple of $f_{1}$, so suppose $r \neq 0$. Then $r$ must be a polynomial in $w$ alone and we can say
>   $$g = a_{1}(uv-w^4) + r(w).$$
>   But by our hypothesis, $g(x^4,y^4,xy)=0$, so we have 
>   $$0 = g(x^4,y^4,xy) = a_{1}(x^4 \cdot y^4 - (xy)^4) + r(w).$$
>   Which implies
>   $$0 = g(x^4,y^4,xy) = 0 + r(xy),$$
>   But since $\mathbb{C}$ is an infinite field we know $r$ must be the zero polynomial, and $g$ is a multiple of $uv-w^4$ as desired.

I feel convinced by my argument but I am a little hesitant since they clearly told me to use exercise 13... Please let me know if my argument fails, and if so maybe enlighten me as to why the argument recommended works. In part (a) it does not make sense to me since it seems to contradict that no term of $r$ is divisible by LT$(f)$ = $uv$?.

Any help greatly appreciated! Let me know if there is any more information I can provide or if anything I said was unclear.

Comment: The cyclic group can act in many different ways, so you must tell us what the action is. The way you have written, it looks as though the action is $\sigma(x)=\omega x, \sigma(y)=\omega^{-1}y$, where $\sigma\in C_4$ is a generator and $\omega$ is the fourth root of 1 (fancy way of saying $i\in\mathbb{C}$. Your arguments seems correct, though you could do this a little more easily by using a suitable grading.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks for the reply, I will update with more information regarding the information and action that led to the invariant ring.

Comment: Information added - @Mohan

Comment: Why must r be a polynomial in w alone? There are no polynomials a1(u,v,w), r(w) for which u=a1(u,v,w)(uv-w^4)+r(w).

Comment: Because if r was not a polynomial alone then the leading term of f, LT(f) = uv, would divde monomial terms of r which the division algorithm assures will not happen? @stewbasic

Comment: @PrinceM this is not true for the polynomial u. It is not a polynomial in w alone, but uv doesn't divide its only monomial.

Comment: Im sorry but im not really sure what you're getting at. Could you perhaps post a more specific answer / explanation? @stewbasic

Comment: The division alg clearly states that no term of r can be divisible by the leading term of uv-w^4 = uv. So if any term of r contains a v or w, then it will be divisible by uv thus can only be of w?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof uses the following claim (paraphrasing slightly):

> If $r$ is a linear combination of monomials with coef in $\mathbb C$, where no monomial is divisible by $uv$, then $r$ must be a polynomial in $w$ alone.

This is not true. For a counterexample, consider $r(u,v,w)=2u+v^3+vw$. This is not a polynomial in $w$ alone, but none of its monomials are divisible by $uv$. Note that each monomial is divisible by either $u$ or $v$, but never both.

Here is a corrected version (it's the same as your exercise 13(a)):

> If $r$ is a linear combination of monomials with coef in $\mathbb C$, where no monomial is divisible by $uv$, then $r$ can be written as $uA(u,w)+vB(v,w)+C(w)$.

To see why, note that no monomial of $r$ can contain both $u$ and $v$, so each belongs to one of the following three groups:

- Monomials containing at least one $u$ and no $v$
- Monomials containing at least one $v$ and no $u$
- Monomials not containing $u$ or $v$.

Monomials in the first group sum to a polynomial of the form $uA(u,w)$. Similarly the second group sums to $vB(v,w)$ and the third to $C(w)$.

Comment: You are entirely right, thank you for the complete and clear answer. Not sure what I was thinking!